# How to tell if Hotkey combination already exists

Tags: c#

I am using Registerhotkey to allow my users to define custom key combinations to perform different actions. The problem I seem to be having is that there is currently no way to check if the key already exists.

For example: One of my testers tried to define "Windows Key + D" not knowing that is the key combination to minimize all windows. So I was curious if there was any way to tell if given a key combination that I could check if that key combination already exists by windows or any other application.

Comment: According to the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx, "Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system." Your application should not allow users to define Windows Key shortcuts.

Comment: That makes since, the problem will still exist for example "Control+C", I would also like to know if a key combination is reserved by another program as well. Basically it would be nice give a key combination to check if it does something if so, than throw an exception yo my users.

Comment: The documentation also says: "RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key." It's possible that some common key combinations are not hot keys. If you want to support those conventions, then your application will have to prevent users from defining conflicting hot keys.

Comment: requires me to make some modification since the last thing I do is registrar the key, but if all I have to do is add `bool didItError = RegisterHotKey(..., ..., ..., ...);` to fix this I am a happy camper! Thank you so much!

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh Could you please roll back your edit and simply post that as an answer? ... And while you are at it, do the same for all your other questions where you did something similar. :O SE doesn't disallow you answering your own question. Keep the question a question, post the answer as an answer.

Comment: No problem... I have done this. Though I can't select it as the answer or vote it up at least for two days :(

Comment: You will just have to wait two days, this is to allow others to possibly post better answers, or down vote yours if it turns out to be wrong. Additionally, there is no need for big 'SOLUTION' headers. That's a given, otherwise it shouldn't be posted. Thanks for adding the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @jim-mischel [for helping me find this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917577/how-to-tell-if-hotkey-combination-already-exists#comment19184326_13917577)!

To check if a hot key exists simply do the following:

```
int ShortcutID = 100; // ID used for this Shortcut Key Combination
uint keyModifier = 2; // This is the Control Key
Char alphanumericKey = "C";
bool didItError
   = RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, ShortcutID, keyModifier, (int)alphanumericKey );
```

Since `Control+C` is a registered key combination by windows the `RegisterHotKey` will return false, if it was not a registered key combination it would return true!

Comment: Funny how it returns `true` for CTRL + V.